# MySQL auto increments ID reset after removing data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to reset MySQL auto increments ID after removing data from MySQL something like that always ID will keep 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. If i remove 4,5,6 ID data then ID will show 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 but not 1,2,3,7,8,9,10 So, the ID will work as serial number not unique ID for each data.

Something like the command but i want to excude the command by php or if have any option from the mysql dashboard

```
SET  @num := 0;

UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1);

ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

I did try the command from php but now working!

Comment: Don't mess with auto increment. Just don't.

Comment: Is there any strictly necessary reason for changing your auto_increment values? If you can't find it, it's better to leave it as is.

Comment: @lemon yes, I need the ID  as the serial number

Comment: Hopefully you aren't using an references in other tables to these IDs then, right? Does the posted code work? If so, you should be able to call it from PHP just the same. Not sure what a "mysql dashboard" is, do you mean something like phpMyAdmin? "but not working" is rarely helpful, make sure you have PHP and MySQL error reporting turned on.

Comment: @NajmulHasan The other commenters are correct that it's best not to mess with auto_increment. You could generate a unique ID and store that in a separate field for the serial ID. However, the code you've pasted is the correct syntax and works. What error are you receiving?

Comment: @ValerieParham-Thompson I can execute the code on the PHPmyadmin SQL section but How can I execute the command by PHP code when I click the delete data button? I can delete database data by the delete button but I want to execute the code alongside the delete command. Will it work?

Comment: `$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM wordmeanings_table WHERE id=".$id);

  $stmt = $con->prepare("SET  @num := 0");
  $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE your_table SET id = @num := (@num+1)");
  $stmt = $con->prepare("ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT =1;");

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();`